# USB debugging in New Nexus 7 on one account

Tags: android, nexus-7

I'm having a problem and i couldn't figure out the solution.

as we know New Nexus 7 comes with Android 4.3,
which we can create multiple account....

Now I have set my main account to enable usb debugging.
But then i figured if i could just create another account and have all of my apps in progress in that account.

I created that account, and settings developer options is nowhere to be found. I guess if i set main account for developer options, then other accounts must be enabled by default.

The problem is, every time i upload my apps via Eclipse, the apps uploaded to both of my accounts. I just want to upload it to my developer account, not my main account. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't - the multi-account feature only separates settings, not full app installations. The apps you install using the Play Store are also shared between accounts, for example. You cannot have multiple versions of the same app installed.